# Div Square, width size based on 100% height

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to make a responsive square with the width size based on the (100%) height of the element. I believe it's impossible using only CSS.

The square width should be equal to the height (100% of the large container. The large container is more than 100% of the screen). The ratio has to be width=height to keep the square.

Comment: You can do this by abusing percentages with `padding-bottom`.

Comment: The problem is that i dont want to define the height by the width, but the width in px using 100% height of the container.

Comment: To be clearer : A square div width based on percentage-based height

Comment: been searching for this too, I guess this is not possible with just CSS

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok here the solution.

```
<div id="square" style="background-color:black;height:100%">test</div>

$(window).ready(updateWidth);
$(window).resize(updateWidth);

function updateWidth()
{
var square = $('#square');
var size = square.height();

square.css('width',size);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j372H/7/

Answer (score 7):

You could do this with a tiny inline image.
No JS, no extra files.

```css
.container {
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background: #acd;
}
     
.square {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  background: #691;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="square">
    <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==" height="100%">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Tigerrrrr Did OP mention he wanted the square to be green? It's just for presentation purposes. Just remove the "text-align" part.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look... at the [`aspect-ratio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio) property.

This property makes creating a square div based on height, in the easiest method possible. Here's some example code:

```css
h2 {
  font-family: calibri;
}

#parent {
  height: 96px;
  width: 256px;
  background: grey;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

#child {
  height: 80px;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  background: lightgrey;
}

#anotherParent {
  height: 96px;
  width: 256px;
  background: grey;
}

#anotherChild {
  height: 50%;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  background: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<h2>Absolute height (80px/96px)</h2>
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">
  </div>
</div>

<h2>Relative height (50%)</h2>
<div id="anotherParent">
  <div id="anotherChild">
  </div>
</div>
```

Here are a couple of links to help you understand the aspect-ratio property:

- https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/aspect-ratio/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio
- https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/115008538927

Answer (score 3):

For a CSS-only solution (where you're sizing relative to the screen size), use [viewport units](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units). For example:

```
@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {
    .box{
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100vh;
    }
}
@media screen and (orientation:portrait) {
    .box{
        height: 100vw;
        width: 100vw;
    }
}
```

(You may want to reduce it to 98 units to eliminate scrolling)

Works great for divs that need to take up a precise proportion of screen space.

[JSFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/9ow3ymfz/)

Comment: That's 100% of the body, not the parent container.

Answer (score 0):

Since a square has same width and the height, and you know the width of the square, you can apply the same value to height.

If you can use JS, then please try this: (jQuery)

```
var wiDth = $('div').css('width'); // get width
$('div').css('height', wiDth); // apply that value to the height
```

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/vpGUK/

Comment: Thank you, the problem is that i dont know the size of the large container. I want to define the square width using the height 100% information.

Comment: I cant set the div with in px. What i try to do is a square width div width based on percentage-based height

Comment: Sorry..but maybe i dont understand : in Jquery you get the width and you apply that value to the height. What i want to do is the inverse : get the height in percent and apply this value in px to the width to do a square.

Comment: Thanks for your helop, i want to do the inverse of this fiddle(dynamic width instead of height) > http://jsfiddle.net/mr8gj/2/

Comment: Then do this: `$('div').css('width', $(this).height());` that was simple! Just change the width with height.. @Sebastien-Gath

Comment: Ok, ive tried but its dont keep the square display > http://jsfiddle.net/vpGUK/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using javascript. I'm assuming that you have a larger div container, in which you want a square, whose height is the same height as the container. The html is as follows:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="square" style="height:100%;">

  </div>
</div>
```

In javascript, you would simply do:

```
<script>
  var container = document.getElementById("container");
  var square = document.getElementById("square");

  square.style.width = container.style.height;

  window.onresize=function(){
    square.style.width = container.style.height;
  };
<script>
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be a good 'css only' solution for you.
Cross browser working.

http://absolide.tumblr.com/post/7317210512/full-css-fluid-squares

Good to highlight this nice css rule:

> If the vertical paddings (and margins) are specified in percent (%) values the size is a percent of the width of the containing element.

Comment: Definitely the best solution, it would be overkill to use js for such a task. There's another good article about this technique: http://www.mademyday.de/css-height-equals-width-with-pure-css.html

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is that the pixel width of the div should be defined by the size of the height (100% of the container).

Comment: to be clearer :
The large container can vary in size, but the div square that should be inside must have dimensions height 100% x 100% height

Comment: Yes, this didn't actually answer sebastian's question: it shows how to size height relative to width, not width relative to height. See my answer for a CSS-only solution.

Comment: [When someone goes on Stack Exchange, the question "answer" should actually contain an answer (including code). Not just a bunch of directions towards the answer.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Put it on your `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>` and try with jquery:

```
var totalHeight = 0;
$("#yourContainer").children().each(function(){ 
    totalHeight += $(this).height;  
});
$("#yourContainer").css('width', totalHeight + 'px');
```

Answer (score -2):

You can assign width and height to the container like this

```css
.container {
    width: 100vh;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

It will create a square div with 100% height and width=height.

Comment: You posted CSS in the style of JavaScript.