# How to style a square div dynamically based on the height?

Tags: html, css

I already read [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20707519/div-square-width-size-based-on-100-height#) and the blog posts that it links to. The problem here is that the referred-to methods *only* work if you have a set width and are setting the height dynamically. But how can you do it if you need the opposite--the height is known but the width is not?

I have a visual element, specified in CSS, that I need to appear consistently in multiple contexts. (For the purposes of this exercise it may as well be a red square.) The contexts have set heights--e.g. a nav with height x, a list-item with height y, etc. The width of the element, therefore, needs to be based on the height -- not the other way around.

I tried reversing the method mentioned in the linked articles (to use `height` instead of `width`, and `padding-right` instead of `padding-top`), but it doesn't work -- the element winds up with no width, and thus the red square (`.my-box .content`) doesn't appear:

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="my-box">
    <div class="content">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="more-stuff">
    Some more stuff goes here
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer {
  background-color: white;
  height: 72px;
  padding: 12px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.my-box {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.my-box::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-left: 100%;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: red;
}

.more-stuff {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  margin-left: 12px;
}
```

[JSFiddle for the above](https://jsfiddle.net/hsoysgab/)

Does anyone know if this is possible without JS or hardcoding the dimensions every time? Googling finds nothing that works for dynamic height--even with quotation marks. :(

Answer (score 1):

JS is the only reliable option in your case.

In CSS box model (and HTML in general) width and height are not symmetric.

In general HTML has "endless tape" layout model - width is fixed (by view/window) but height is not known upfront - needs to be calculated.

CSS does layout in following steps:

1. do horizontal layout inside left and right bounds. At the end this will give you content height.
2. If `height:auto` (by default) set element height computed at step #1.
3. Do vertical alignment if needed (table-cell and flexbox elements).

Mathematically speaking `height = F(width,content)` and F here is a [step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Step_function) - different input width values may give you same output height value. Step function has no determined inverse function - there is no such an [inverse function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function) F' that will allow you to calculate `width = F'(height,content)`.

(My pardon for the math on pure CSS subject, but I don't know how to explain it otherwise.)

Comment: To explain the mathematical section: height may be based on width, but width cannot be based on height.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit a hack, but still a solution.
We create a box with ratio 1:1, set the width and rotate box `transform: rotateZ(90deg)`.

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  background-color: #F72F4E;
  overflow: hidden;
}


.Box {
  width: 50vmin; /* or 400px for ex. */
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(90deg);
          transform: rotateZ(90deg);
}

.Box:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 100%;
}

.Box__content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 12px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-90deg);
          transform: rotateZ(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="Box">
  <div class="Box__content">Box</div>
</div>
```

P.S.: SVG can be useful in that case, i hope.

Comment: It will not works, if you want to inherit square side from the parent. width: 30% will not work. Only vmin and fixed sizes.