# Creating a responsive square based on the vertical side

Tags: html, css

I have an *absolutely* positioned container that I need to make a responsive square of based on its *height* (not width, so the `padding-bottom` trick won't work).

So far I've been using a square image inside the container to keep its proportions:

https://codepen.io/Deka87/pen/xrXgoK

HTML:

```
<div class="relative">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores placeat eius cum non eum suscipit, facilis nulla, porro, quasi voluptate quaerat amet vitae, illum quam omnis. Placeat, fuga excepturi tempore?
  <div class="absolute">
    <img src="square.png" alt="..." />
  </div>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
.relative {
  position: relative;
}
.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  background-color: fade-out(green, .5);

  > img {
    height: 100%; width: auto;
  }
}
```

which works fine in Chrome, but NOT Firefox, which is the issue I am addressing.

For some reason Firefox ignores the content of the absolutely positioned element and sets its width equal to 0 unless different is specified (which might be even more intuitive though).

Any help would be highly appreciated!

PS: Below is a screenshot of the green rectangle I am after:

[image]

It is what it looks like in Chrome and how I was hoping it to look in Firefox (and Safari).

Comment: I don't think this is possible with CSS. It is possible with jQuery. https://stackoverflow.com/a/20936189/8085668

Comment: @WizardCoder, but it does work in Chrome. I still hope I am missing something simple.

Comment: Just checked in chrome and I can see what you want now. I thought you wanted to retain the aspect ratio of the div. I will take another look.

Comment: In iOS Safari, I see a rectangle with vertical sides longer than horizontal sides (but width > 0). Is this what you're after, or do you need a true square with all four sides equal?

Comment: @cantera, I need the green rectangle to be a perfect square (the way it works in Chrome now). Seems like it doesn't work in Safari too.

Comment: it looks like firefox is having issues loading the transparent image itself, so that may be the root cause